# Issue with Varnish Cache while adding or editing a Product in Catalogue

Tags: varnish, centos

Whenever I try to edit or create a new product on my Magneto 2.3 website, I am getting 503 Error in Varnish.

Upon checking the log entries I found the below error message and am unsure how to fix it. Any help, please..

> Mar 28 07:57:25 <server.hostname> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1
> 56896 127.0.0.1 6082 Rd X-Magento-Tags-Pattern:
> ((^|,)cat_p_23071(,|$))
>
> Mar 28 07:57:25 <server.hostname> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1
> 56896 127.0.0.1 6082 Wr 101 Unknown request.
> Type 'help' for more info.
> all commands are in lower-case.

> Mar 28 07:57:25 <server.hostname>
> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 56896 127.0.0.1 6082 Rd Host:
> localhost

> Mar 28 07:57:25 <server.hostname> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet
> 127.0.0.1 56896 127.0.0.1 6082 Wr 101 Unknown request.
> Type 'help' for more info.
> all commands are in lower-case.

> Mar 28 07:57:35 <server.hostname>
> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 56900 127.0.0.1 6082 Rd PURGE /
> HTTP/1.1

> Mar 28 07:57:35 <server.hostname> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet
> 127.0.0.1 56900 127.0.0.1 6082 Wr 101 Unknown request.
> Type 'help' for more info.
> all commands are in lower-case.

> Mar 28 07:57:35 <server.hostname>
> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 56900 127.0.0.1 6082 Rd
> X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: ((^|,)cat_p_23071(,|$))

> Mar 28 07:57:35
> <server.hostname> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 56900 127.0.0.1
> 6082 Wr 101 Unknown request.
> Type 'help' for more info.
> all commands are in lower-case.

> Mar 28 07:57:35 <server.hostname>
> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 56900 127.0.0.1 6082 Rd Host:
> localhost

> Mar 28 07:57:35 <server.hostname> varnishd[1134]: CLI telnet
> 127.0.0.1 56900 127.0.0.1 6082 Wr 101 Unknown request.
> Type 'help' for more info.
> all commands are in lower-case

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that there is an issue with the Varnish configuration. You may want to check the Varnish configuration file to ensure that it is set up correctly for your Magento website.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs you provided, it seems like there are telnet requests being sent to Varnish with invalid or unknown commands. These requests are likely not related to the normal functioning of your website and may be caused by a misconfiguration or security issue.

To troubleshoot this issue, you can check the following:

1. Check your Varnish configuration files to ensure that they are properly configured and secure. You can consult the official Varnish documentation for guidance on how to do this.
2. Check your server logs for any other suspicious activity or requests.
3. Check if there are any scripts or tools on your server that may be making these requests.
4. You can also consider blocking telnet access to your Varnish server to prevent unauthorized access.

It is important to ensure the security of your server and investigate any suspicious activity to prevent potential security breaches.